# Can we request OAuth 2 scopes in OIDC?

Tags: oauth, openid-connect, scopes

I know that OIDC is used for federated authentication and in the /authorize endpoint we can pass standard/custom scopes like *openid profile name email* etc. And based on the scopes we add the claims in the ID token, and also an access token is issued with these scopes and the client can use the access token to invoke **/userinfo** endpoint. And in response we return user information based on the OIDC scopes.

Similarly in case of OAuth2.0 clients can request OAuth scopes (based on scopes supported on resource server) like *create-api read-api delete-api* etc; and upon user's consent, access token is issued with these scopes.

My question is : In the OIDC, can a client pass both OIDC and OAuth scopes? For eg. in the  /authorize endpoint can a client pass scopes like ***openid name read-api write-api admin*** which issues **ID token** and an **access token** with all these scopes? And access token can be used to invoke both /userinfo endpoint and to access user's resources?  Is this a standard practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in fact all scopes are "OAuth 2.0" scopes as OpenID Connect is a superset of OAuth 2.0. Scopes are in fact not tied to the ID Token, they are tied to the access token. The resulting access token can be used to invoke both the user info endpoint as well as any other OAuth 2.0 protected resources.